# Blazor Webassembly shows only loading screen when using Ingress

Tags: blazor-webassembly, ingress-nginx

I am trying to get my Blazor Webassembly running in Kubernetes. There is a service `customer-pwa-svc` that i can call with `http://localhost:{assignedPort}` and my Webassembly starts perfectly. So far it looks good and I my container is running as expected.
Now I want to get access from outside and want to use the ingress object with the following rule

```
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            service: 
              name: customer-pwa-svc
              port: 
                number: 80
          pathType: Exact
```

when I now call localhost, i only see a black loading circle
[loadingscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqNAc.png)

In the dev tools I see the 404 errors, that the files cant be loaded
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9He1U.png)

But it has the correct index.html loaded.

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "./Customer.PWA.sln"
RUN dotnet build "./Customer.PWA.sln" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./Customer.PWA.sln" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM nginx:alpine AS final
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=publish /app/publish/wwwroot .
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

and the nginx.conf:

```
events { }
http {
    include mime.types;
   
    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
    }
}
```

When I connect to the pod and in the folder `/usr/share/nginx/html` I see all files and folders I expect, including _content and framework stuff from Blazor Webassembly.

What I also tried was just to use another image (like nginx) behind my `customer-pwa-svc` and when I then called localhost the nginx side was shown without problems.

What I am wondering is, why does everything works, when calling my service directly, but not when using the ingress rules. I guess there is a path problem, but I don't see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was too obvious to see. The problem was in the pathtype. When I changed it to `Prefix` everything works as expected.